# Issue with reading Excel Data using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi, out-of-memory

Dears, I have a problem reading the Excel data and loading it to DB which is more than 15000 rows as it is causing OutOfMemory error. It's a Java Swing application where there is one action to load the excel and another action is there to write complete data to DB.

Is it possible to read around 3000 records every time and load it to cache and then write it to DB without causing Memory Issue instead of loading 15k records at a time ?  Anyone can help me?

Comment: You would need to post an example of your code demonstrating the problem, along with any error messages you get.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will add it in some time !

Comment: You may need to consider using a streaming approach - I presume you're currently using XSSFWorkbook or HSSFWorkbook which hold all the data from the workbook in memory. See https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java or https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader

Comment: Dear Fanning, I was able to read the data using Excel Streaming Reader but it is not considering blank spaces. Suppose, If the first column is empty in an excel, It is filling up that data with the values of second columns when I read. Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Maybe you should submit a bug report to excel-streaming-reader team. If the excel-streaming-reader isn't working for you, maybe you could try using the example I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader`.
This library uses SAX parser to read xlsx files, which is also very memory efficient.
Second option is to use `excel-streaming-reader`. It contains cell information also. It also works perfectly if there are empty cells.
I have done using both methods.

Comment: It's good to see some positive suggestions. You can improve your answer by providing some example code.